# How to control the direction for the Build modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm practicing with the [Build modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/build.html). I understand its basic functionality but I can not figure out, why it starts revealing one section of the mesh from the top, and the next section on the bottom and finally starts to build up the model.

[image]

**Q:** Is there a way just to get the modifier to build up from one direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Build Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/build.html) will use the vertices index number to determine their apparition order. These indices are determined by their order of creation. In your case, if the *Build* modifier displays the top, then the bottom, then the rest, it's probably because you've created the horizontal edge loops with a bevel operation. With successive extrusions the order will have gone from top to bottom.

To display the *Indices* option in 2.9, enable [*Preferences > Interface > Developer Extras*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/interface.html#display), then go in *Edit Mode*, select the vertices and enable the *Indices* option in the  *Viewport Overlays* panel.

To sort the vertices the way you want, go in *Edit Mode*, put the [3D Cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html) where you want, it will determine the last numbers, select all, in *Mesh > Sort Elements > Cursor Distance*, then in the *Operator* box click on the *Face* button.

For more complicated objects than simple vertical/horizontal ones there must be some addons or python codes that allow to sort the vertices index numbers.

You can play with the *Build* modifier *Start* value, if you want the object to be deconstructed instead of constructed, click on *Reversed*.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that certainly worked great, just one thing though. I cannot find the indices you told me in the overlay panel. I googled and saw a few screenshots, but cannot find in my blender 2.91. On the left is my overlay panel, and on the right is the one from google. Where is the feature not residing? I tried to google it and nothing seems to show it. https://ibb.co/NTtdpJX

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer

Comment: @moonboots Thanks a lot I didnt know about the "Sort Elements" abilities :) Great to know :) Just it doesn't seem to have an effect to Build modifier for me, tested 2.82 and 2.92.

Comment: mmh yes it has an effect, you must miss a step. Too bad it's not easier to choose the vertex index though...

Comment: wow....how great is that?!!!!!!

Comment: I think you should BOLD the select all in edit mode

Comment: @ yossico, hello, could you please tell a bit more?

Comment: For a complicated looping structure my idea was to select one end and then use Ctrl+Num+ to add selection, and then sort by selected.

Comment: @vklidu I had to look at the operator panel and change from Vertices to Faces, I see it's in the answer but I didn't know if it was always there or if you missed it.  I did :)

Comment: @AllenSimpson ... Ha :) Thanks man, awesome ... good catch. With "Selected" order sounds great, but now this didn't work for me :) 3.4 ... any trick here I missed? again :)

Comment: For me (3.2) the build modifier uses the face indices (not vert indices) to build the mesh. Meaning you need to select all faces in face mode and then 'Reverse' in 'Sort Elements'.

Comment: Oh Ok I didn't know that, I'll test it, thanks