# How to reveal a logo as if it is being drawn?

Tags: modifiers

I have a trademarked logo of 2 heart shapes (not filled) joined together like number 8. It is similar to the infinity sign. How can I reveal it as if it is being drawn?

[image]

I can use the build modifier, if the faces are sorted accordingly. But I don't know how to sort the faces of this object according to this path. In essence, the logo, which is in the shape similar to that of the number 8, should be animated as if it is being drawn (or being built, according to the terminology of the build modifier).

Comment: have you tried with the Array + Curve modifiers?

Comment: @moonboots I don't know how to do that. The only way I know is to use build modifier, but it has the prerequisite of sorting the faces according to this path, which I don't know how.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/206192/110840

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question, since as a beginner this is the way I was able to do. The resulting render took only 10 or so seconds in my very old laptop (without GPU, using i3 processor).

**Make the shape**

1. Delete the default cube.
2. Add a mesh circle
3. Using proportional editing with sharp falloff, dragging it to heart shape.
4. Duplicate the resulting heart shape
5. Rotate it 180 degrees
6. Extrude
7. Bevel

**Create the drawing**

1. Bisect the image twice at the centre, to get a half heart.
2. Sort the faces using the Mesh menu in the Edit mode, placing the 3D cursor on one end.
3. In another blender file, copy this object and use reverse sort.
4. Copy this object back to the original Blender file, rotate it along x and y axes (depending on original orientation of your object) by 180 degrees.
5. Join them with Ctrl+j as a single object.
6. Make a copy of this new blender file, and repeat this process.

In a total of 5 minutes effort, you can make an initial animation. Further refinements can be done, but I need to figure that out.

[image: First attempt in Making Drawing animation]

**Converting to gif**

As an extra, the resulting render in mp4 can be converted to gif format simply by the command (in the terminal)

```
ffmpeg -i DrawLogo.mp4 -loop 0 DrawLogo.gif
```

As per my understanding,

1. The -i indicates input
2. -loop 0 indicates infinite looping

**Further refinements**

The animation at this stage looks slightly discontinuous in the centre. Probably some advanced users can help in this matter. I hope that this answer is helpful for other beginners like me.

Answer (score 5):

i would make a curve with that shape, give it some bevel and animate the factor end:

[image]

Comment: I am new to Blender. I made this shape using mesh circle and using proportional editing with sharp falloff, dragging it, and duplicating the resulting heart shape and rotating it 180 degrees, then extruding and bevelling. I don't know to make it using bézier curves. I will try it the next day and get back to you. Upvoted.