# Controling Direction of Build Modifier on a Curve Object

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am wondering if there is a way to control the order that a build modifier builds a curve object. I'm aware that when applying a build modifier to a mesh, you can sort the faces of the mesh to tell the build modifier which order to build things in, as explained in the answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206188/how-to-control-the-direction-for-the-build-modifier/206192#206192). However, I can't find a similar way to sort the vertices (I think vertices is the wrong term here) on a curve object. If possible, I'd rather avoid converting my curve to a mesh.

If it matters, here is specifically what I'm working with. I have a math expression that I've imported into Blender from an svg file. By default what I get are a bunch of curve objects which I've joined together into a single curve object.

[image]

I want to animate this expression to appear (kind of like it's being written). For that I've applied a build modifier, but I'm not quite happy with the order that things are being built. I could convert it to a mesh, sort the vertices, and then apply the build modifier. However, this is a pain because the converted mesh is a mess, so I first have to remesh the whole thing, and use a ton of geometry to get the text and the animation to look right. I'd rather just keep it as a curve if possible.

Comment: You can roughly control the order in which single characters are filled by separating them from the same object and then joining them one by one again back to the same bezier curve object. The order you join them by will determine the order they are filled in. Other than that, if you actually want to simulate a writing stroke along the character shape, you will likely have to tailor it manually, most fonts don't have that kind of information built in. The build modifier only follows whatever random order the curve fill algorithm uses internally to create visible faces.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps

Comment: Thanks, it looks like these links will be helpful and good enough for what I'm trying to do. Appreciate it.